# How can I add inactive class in bxslider control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, bxslider

I need to add class inactive in prev if first slider and for next if end of the slider.

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      nextSelector: '#slider-next',
      prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
      nextText: 'Nex →',
      prevText: '← Prev',
      infiniteLoop: false,
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uewLafk1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://bxslider.com/options) for the `bxSlider` plugin, there's an `onSlideAfter` callback which triggers after every transition. In addition, it has methods for `getCurrentSlide` and `getSlideCount`.

Using all of these three, you can do the following:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
nextSelector: '#slider-next',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
nextText: 'Next →',
prevText: '← Prev',
infiniteLoop: false,
onSlideAfter: function() {
   if (slider.getCurrentSlide() == 0)
     // First slide
     $('#slider-prev').addClass('inactive');
   else if (slider.getCurrentSlide() == slider.getSlideCount() - 1)
     // Last slide
     $('#slider-next').addClass('inactive');
   else
     $('#slider-next, #slider-prev').removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbfdebzg/